# exact copy of a string to array string! DPLL algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I think being so close to the solution but I can not find it. I'm implementing a sort of DPLL algorithm in two ways. The first that take automatically the input from a file and the second (the same) that it want the input manually from console. The second works nice, but the first has some problem
Both my input are in this form: [-8,6,1] [4,10,-1] [7,-5,3] [10,-8,3] [10,-8,-6] [5,-3,6]. This class need to manage the acquisition from file.

```
package ausiliare;
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.*;

//import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Lettura {
    public static int getInt() throws IOException {



    String content = null;
    File folder = new File("C:\\Solution.txt");

    content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder) + "\n";

    int outside = Integer.parseInt(content.substring(0,
            content.indexOf("[")).trim());
    return outside;
}

public static String getString() throws IOException {

    String content = null;
    File folder = new File("C:\\Solution.txt");
    content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder) + "\n";
    String remainingString = content.substring(content.indexOf("["),
            content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1);
    // System.out.println(remainingString);
    return remainingString;

}

public static String[] arg() throws IOException {
String[] strArray = getString().split("");//here i don't really do
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
    return strArray;
}
```

}

This part is not necessary in the second algorithm (where i copy manually the solution). 
the problem is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<Clausola> formula = new LinkedList<Clausola>();
        int n = Lettura.getInt();
        String[] arg = Lettura.arg();
        parseClauses(formula, arg, n);
        System.out.println("Il numero di Letterali utilizzati:"+n);
        System.out.println("La tua formula k-CNF:"+Lettura.getString());
        boolean[] solution = solveDPLL(n, formula);
```

-------------------------------------------------------------- (other things)

```
public static void parseClauses(List<Clausola> F, String[] arg, int N) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arg.length; i++) {
```

My problem is about String[] arg = Lettura.arg(). This method does not acquire the same input that would give manually. I hope to be clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want chars? I'm not sure you can split a string using the character `""`

Comment: no in fact i'm not really sure. my parseClauses method want a String[]arg. do you suggest other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a String[] array. Instead use a char[] array. You can convert a string to a char[] by using the following method.

```
String s = "foo";
char[] charArray = s.toCharyArray();
```

charArray = `{f, o, o}`

If you simply *must* use a String[] array, then I would do this:

```
String s = "foo";
char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
String[] sA = new String[charrArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < sA.length; i++) {
    sA[i] = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: wont work because there is no constructor `String(char)`. Do `String.valueOf(charArray[i]);` instead-